# How to add titles between plots

Tags: r, ggplot2

For the sake of simplicity, let's assume I have four graphs:

```
data("midwest", package = "ggplot2")
p1<-ggplot(midwest, aes(x=area, y=poptotal)) + geom_point()
p2<-ggplot(midwest, aes(x=area, y=poptotal)) + geom_point()
p3<-ggplot(midwest, aes(x=area, y=poptotal)) + geom_point()
p4<-ggplot(midwest, aes(x=area, y=poptotal)) + geom_point()
grid.arrange(p1,p2,p3,p4,ncol=2)
```

Now, I want to create a title (TITLE 1, TITLE 2) between each two titles,, as presented below: 
[image]

Any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a gtable solution to your problem. There might be easier solutions out there, but this should work.

First we'll bake in some titles in the leftmost plots

```
library(grid) # needed later for plotting

data("midwest", package = "ggplot2")
p1<-ggplot(midwest, aes(x=area, y=poptotal)) + geom_point() + ggtitle("Title 1")
p2<-ggplot(midwest, aes(x=area, y=poptotal)) + geom_point()
p3<-ggplot(midwest, aes(x=area, y=poptotal)) + geom_point() + ggtitle("Title 2")
p4<-ggplot(midwest, aes(x=area, y=poptotal)) + geom_point()
```

Then we can `cbind` and `rbind` the plots together as we see fit.

```
p12 <- cbind(ggplotGrob(p1), ggplotGrob(p2), size = "first")
p34 <- cbind(ggplotGrob(p3), ggplotGrob(p4), size = "first")

all <- rbind(p12, p34, size = "first")

grid.newpage(); grid.draw(all)
```

Note that we'd have to work with `grid.newpage()` and `grid.draw()` to get our plots, since we've left the ggplot sphere and are now in the realm of gtables and grid. Anyway, resulting plot looks like the following:

[image]

From your example I expect that you want these titles to be centered. This will be a bit more finicky:

```
# Decide what is a title
is_title <- grep("^title$", all$layout$name)
# Grab all titles
titles <- all$grobs[is_title]
# Exclude empty titles
is_title <- is_title[!sapply(titles, inherits, "zeroGrob")]

# Center title
all$grobs[is_title] <- lapply(all$grobs[is_title], function(title) {
  title$children[[1]]$hjust <- 0.5
  title$children[[1]]$x <- unit(0.5, "npc")
  title
})

# Spread title over all panels
# You can see the number you'd need from the l/r coordinates of the 'panel' grobs
# which you can find by printing `all` or `all$layout`.
all$layout[is_title, "r"] <- 14 


grid.newpage(); grid.draw(all)
```

[image]

EDIT: added example for adding extra titles

You can add extra titles, but you would need the gtable package for this.

```
library(gtable)

# First make extra titles
left <- textGrob("Left Title", gp = gpar(fontsize = 13.2, col = "black",
                                         lineheight = 0.9, font = 1))
right <- textGrob("Right Title", gp = gpar(fontsize = 13.2, col = "black",
                                           lineheight = 0.9, font = 1))

# Find a height that was 0, assign new height based on extra title
all$heights[[2]] <- unit(1, "grobheight", left)
# Add the titles (t = top position, l = left position)
all <- gtable_add_grob(all, left, t = 2, l = 5, clip = "off")
all <- gtable_add_grob(all, right, t = 2, l = 14, clip = "off")

grid.newpage(); grid.draw(all)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! That was extremely helpful!!  Is there a way to add 2 more titles (both above TITLE 1),   T1: above "left graphs" and T2: above "right graphs".   I.E one title above the left column graphs, and one title above the right column graphs.